# Can I only display 10 labels in X Axis of XtraChart line control of DevExpress?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, label, overlapping, xtrachart

I am using DevExpress XtraChart control, my chart is a line chart. If I set ((XYDiagram)lineChart.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeMeasureUnit = DateTimeMeasurementUnit.Minute; and ((XYDiagram)lineChart.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeGridAlignment =  DateTimeMeasurementUnit.Minute. And if I have millions of data points in one series, I see the labels on X Axis are too many.

I don't want so many labels to display, I think I can set ((XYDiagram)lineChart.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeGridAlignment to either hours,or day, or month or year.

But the problem is I don't know how many data points is there on the series. The number is dynamic.

Is there a way no matter how many data points are there on the series, I always only display e.g. 10 labels of X Axis? Or is there any way I can manipulate AxisX.DateTimeGridAlignment and AxisX.DateTimeMeasureUnit, so I only display 10 labels?

Thank you!